# Free CORS proxy

Tags: mongodb, cors, couchdb, cloud-storage, nosql

I have a chrome extensions that, for now, uses storage.sync as a data store.
I am trying upgrade to a more robust data store (cloudant, iriscouch) so I can expand what the extension can do.

The problem I am facing is that none of the free cloud store options I have seen (cloudant, iriscouch, mongolab) support cors (or in case of mongolab - free tier is not enough)

So I have fewquestions:

1. Is there a free nosql cloud store option that fully supports cors?
2. If not, is there a free proxy that I can use. I have tried http://www.corsproxy.com/ but it only seems to support GET so it's not enough for me.
3. How would you solves this problem for free and without hosting anything on my own hardware.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudant will have CORS support from January 2014. Iris Couch also supports CORS, just not via a UI - you have to modify the configuration via the CouchDB API.

[Couchappy](https://www.couchappy.com) supports [CORS and PouchDB](https://www.couchappy.com/faq), and introduces a [selective domain security](https://www.couchappy.com/news) feature, which allows fine-grained security(https only or both https+http) on a per-domain basis.

Comment: I came to the same answer since I have asked this question.